# MySQLi bind_param issue in my function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a function which handles MySQLi prepared queries for me. This function is designed so it's easy to type and so that I don't need to type out 3-4 lines to get a simple query to work. Here is the code:

```
public function preparedQuery($query, $values, $display = false)
{    
    $mysqli = $this->connectDatabase();

    $repeat = str_repeat('?', count($values));
    $repeat = trim($repeat, ',');

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));

    $bind = array();

    foreach($values as $key => $val)
    {
        $bind[$key] = &$values[$key];
    }
    var_dump($query, $types, $bind);

    array_unshift($bind, $types);
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $bind);

    $stmt->execute();

    if($display)
    {
        $res = $stmt->get_result();

        return $res->fetch_assoc();
    }
        return true;
}
```

As you can see this function does most things for me. I can run SELECT, UPDATE and SELECT queries and it will execute just fine. However when I attempt to run INSERT queries I get the following error:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\system\mysqli.class.php on line 40
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\system\mysqli.class.php on line 42

What I'm attempting to run is:

For reference here are some usage examples:

> var_dump($db->preparedQuery("INSERT INTO texts (indentifier, display_text) VALUES (?, ?)", array('test1', 'test2')));

This is the output of var_dump:

> string(59) "INSERT INTO texts (indentifier, display_text) VALUES (?, ?)" string(2) "ss" array(2) { [0]=> &string(5) "test1" [1]=> &string(5) "test2" }

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `echo $mysqli->error` after the `prepare` and see if there is one.

Comment: what does connectDatabase() function do?

Comment: Yeah. This is the error @MichaelRushton `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\mysqli.class.php on line 28`

Comment: @YourCommonSense it connects to the database.

Comment: Every time you run a query?

Comment: Then `$this->connectDatabase()` isn't returning a `mysqli` object. You'll want to look at that method.

Comment: It is returning a mysqli object. The function works with every query except INSERT. That's what the error is `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\mysqli.class.php on line 40

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\mysqli.class.php on line 42`

Comment: If `$mysqli->error` triggers the notice `Trying to get property of non-object` then `$mysqli` isn't an object.

Comment: I just did var_dump($mysqli). It's too long to paste so I've screenshot it. http://puu.sh/5xFpK.png